# Rails params, params.merge error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

In order to keep params `filter` and `filter_type` through a ajax form submit, I pass them in as hidden fields in my `article` form which as a result gives me this params hash:

`{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "article"=>{"filter"=>"xxx", "filter_type"=>"xxxx", ....actual fields of the model that got updated...}, "commit"=>"Update Article", "controller"=>"articles", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"xxx"}`

Which means I can access them through `params[:article]["filter"]`.

When I, in my controller's update method, call `params.merge(filter: params[:article]["filter"])` nothing gets appended. When I try `params = params.merge(filter: params[:article]["filter"])` I get this error `NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass):`

and here comes the weird part: When I do `@foo = params.merge(filter: params[:article]["filter"])` I also don't get anything added until I actually output `@foo` in the view. As soon as I have the `<%= @foo %>` in my view, the params get properly merged. Can somebody explain why that is?

Comment: what if you fetch like `params["article"]["filter"]` did you get anything

Comment: I think it is better for you to not pass them as `articles` child. Instead of using `f.hidden_field :filter` you could use `hidden_field_tag :filter`, so you will receive the params like: `{ filter: "filter", article: {}}`. This way there is no need to merge.

Comment: yeah, I tried using the `hidden_field_tag` but it wasn't working for some reason with `simple_form` but now it does. make it an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @Killerpixler Done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better for you to not pass them as articles child. Instead of using `f.hidden_field :filter` you could use `hidden_field_tag :filter`, so you will receive the params like: `{ filter: "filter", article: {}}`. This way there is no need to merge.